# Open CSS horizontal accordion and scroll to top on page load

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, slider, accordion

I currently have a page with a CSS accordion [here](http://thirdsectorfilms.com/what_we_do.html#acc3); as you can see, in order to have the page load with the accordion open instead of closed, i have the link point to one of the accordion sections, #acc3.

The problem with this is that the page automatically scolls down to center the accordion (on smaller viewports) I want the page to default to scroll top. I have tried using

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
$('html').scrollTop(0);
```

});

but that does not seem to be helping. Any Idea? - Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that the solution you're using is great to rely on anchor links alone. I understand that it acts as some kind of pagination, but as you said - the fact that on load it's jumping to the element is a bit crummy.

I also really don't like the fact that if no anchor is set, then none of them are open. I'd much prefer it if the first one was your "default". However, I can't think of a good way to achieve this using CSS off the top of my head,  unless you were to explicitly mention `#acc2:not(:target), #acc3:not(:target)` etc (maybe this would be easier in CSS4 if we get a parent selector - though I'm not sure how).

If you really want to achieve this with the existing solution, then using `$("html,body").scrollTop(0)` should work, but I also remember having issues relating to trying to instantly set the scroll position using jQuery. Try adding a timeout (could be really minimal like 1ms) and see if that helps:

```
// Try de/increasing the 200 and see if that helps
setTimeout(function() {
    $("html, body").scrollTop(0)
}, 200);
```

However, I'd still rather you recruited JavaScript a little more too, such as an initial check for a hash starting `#acc` and if there's none then focus on one of the elements (a default).

Comment: great - i'm actually just using $("html,body").scrollTop(0) without the timeout. Will use this until I sort out a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: He **could** do this, but surely there's a better way to instantiate his accordion and focus on the first element rather than jumping to an anchor and using JS to jump right back?

Comment: hmm no luck i'm afraid, the problem seems to be that linking directly to one of the accordion elements seems to be bypassing/ignoring the jquery call.

Comment: $(function() {
   $('body').scrollTop(0);
});